# Highlight all Sundays in a month

Tags: php, calendar

I've been searching everywhere and I just got confused like crazy. I'd like to highlight all the Sundays in a month and with the code I currently have, I don't know where exactly should I insert the code to highlight the Sundays. Or maybe the code is wrong... any help, please?

If we have the month of December, it should highlight 4, 11, 18 and 25, with 12 highlighted as the current day (id='focus') in the image attached:
[image]

The code to display the days is (which only shows the highlighted current day):

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
if($i < $startday) echo "";
elseif(($i - $startday + 1) == $cDay){
   echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' class='tableBody' id='focus'>". ($i - $startday + 1) ."</td>";
}
else {
   if (($i - $startday + 1) == date("j") && ($cMonth-1) == date("F")) {
      echo "<td class='tableBody' align='center' valign='middle'>".  ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
   }
   else {
      echo "<td class='tableBody' align='center' valign='middle'>".  ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
   }
}
}
```

I'm so lost on how to get this output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

date("N")   ISO-8601 numeric representation of the day of the week (added in PHP 5.1.0) 1 (for Monday) through 7 (for Sunday)

You can check if the date is equal to 7

```
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];

for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
    if($i < $startday)  {
        echo "";
    }
    elseif(date("N F", mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,($i - $startday + 1),$cYear)) == 7){ 
        // Sunday
        echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' class='tableBody' id='focus'>". ($i - $startday + 1) ."</td>";
    }
    else {
        if (($i - $startday + 1) == date("j") && ($cMonth-1) == date("F")) {
            echo "<td class='tableBody' align='center' valign='middle'>".  ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<td class='tableBody' align='center' valign='middle'>".  ($i - $startday + 1) . "</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much, you're fantastic! (/n_n)/